# Two overlapping lines causing darker shades

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I got a vector map of India and am trying to make my own edits.
Everything has been going well except for one small point.

[image]

As you can see from this image, each state is counted twice in the "inner" lines, making interior borders from states doubly shaded whereas exterior border of india is lighter. I would like the interior and exterior borders to have the same opacity. How can I do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Adding to my first question.. If I would like to blacken the exterior border and have a lighter shade of grey dividing states, how could I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by opacity. if you have transparent lines, you will see other lines behind them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a map where the lines for each state overlap perfectly.  Perhaps yours are slightly apart.  Try not to use opacity to control the colour, select grey values if you need to instead.

Map with perfectly overlapping states : http://www.vecteezy.com/map-vector/35270-india-state-map-outline

I have made a quick video of how I might do it:
http://youtu.be/Giyu-Uu5OeI

For individual states just select them bring them to the front and alter their stroke colour.

You can draw outlines around combined states by selecting them ... duplicating them, pasting them in place, bringing them to the front and uniting them. Then alter their stroke and fill.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is actually the map I was using. Perhaps I changed something when I was working with it. I'll redownload it and try following your instructions. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much, you've literally just made my day! Cheers mate!

Comment: No problem glad it you got it sorted :)    Can you mark the answer as useful ?